# Update the position of the rectangle patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, patch

I rotate a rectangle and am able to plot it correctly within my figure.
However when I access the coordinates of the rotated rectangle, they appear to be the same as original one.

How to access the updated coordinates?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib as mpl

from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cx, cy = 6,7
l, w = 3,4
angle = np.deg2rad(30)

ts = ax.transData
t = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_around(cx,cy,angle)
tr =  t + ts

rect0 = patches.Rectangle((cx - l/2.0,
                        cy - w/2.0), l,w, fill=False, color="blue", alpha=0.50)
rect1 = patches.Rectangle((cx - l/2.0,
                        cy - w/2.0), l,w, color="blue",  alpha=0.50, transform=tr)


print(rect0.get_bbox())
print(rect1.get_bbox())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the rectangle's bounding box does not change. Using a transform like you do here means that the rectangle is transformed when being drawn on screen. The rectangle itself will not change at all.

In order to obtain the coordinates of the transformed rectangle you need to apply the transform to the coordinates as shown in [Get coordinates of the rotated patch (rectangle) matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306012/get-coordinates-of-the-rotated-patch-rectangle-matplotlib)

```
coords = rect1.get_bbox().get_points()
print(t.transform(coords))
```