# Getting the points of a matplotlib Rectangle in axes coordinate system?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to obtain the coordinates of the points of a `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` in the "axes" coordinate system, which in https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html notes:

> "axes" - The coordinate system of the Axes; (0, 0) is bottom left of the axes, and (1, 1) is top right of the axes. - `ax.transAxes`
>
> ...
>
> `self.transLimits` is the transformation that takes you from data to axes coordinates; i.e., it maps your view xlim and ylim to the unit space of the axes (and `transAxes` then takes that unit space to display space)

Ok, so consider the following example:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)

x = 0 ; y = 0 ; width = 100; height = 50; 
rect = mpatches.Rectangle((x, y), width, height, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='#AAAAAA88')
patch = ax.add_patch(rect)

x = 10 ; y = 10 ; width = 40; height = 20; 
rect2 = mpatches.Rectangle((x, y), width, height, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='red')
patch = ax.add_patch(rect2)

print(f"{rect2.get_extents()=}")
print(f"{rect2.get_path().vertices=}")
rdatapoints = rect2.get_patch_transform().transform(rect2.get_path().vertices) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315897/6197439
print(f"{rdatapoints=}")
print(f"{ax.transLimits.transform(rdatapoints)=}")

plt.show()
```

The plot produced is:

[image: matplotlib plot]

Roughly, I'd expect lower left point of rect2 in axes coordinates to be at xy (0.1, 0.2), and the upper right point of rect2 to be at (0.5, 0.6).

However, I don't understand how I can obtain those coordinates; I have tried several things in the code above, and the printout is:

```
rect2.get_extents()=Bbox([[5040.0, 3748.7999999999997], [24880.0, 11140.8]])
rect2.get_path().vertices=array([[0., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 0.]])
rdatapoints=array([[10., 10.],
       [50., 10.],
       [50., 30.],
       [10., 30.],
       [10., 10.]])
ax.transLimits.transform(rdatapoints)=array([[10., 10.],
       [50., 10.],
       [50., 30.],
       [10., 30.],
       [10., 10.]])
```

So,

- `rect2.get_extents()` produces numbers that are waaaaaaay out of either the data or axes coordinates for that item on the plot;
- `rect2.get_path()` apparently keeps it vertices as just straight 0 and 1
- I can get the coordinates in "data" coordinate system in `rdatapoints` - but trying to transform them with `transLimits` results in ... exactly the same numbers?!

I really don't understand what is going on here ...

So, how can I get the points of the rect2 Rectangle on the plot in the "axes" coordinate system of the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reading chapter 2 from the Nicolas Rougier's book on this, if you're interested in understanding the coordinate systems, it already provides example of exactly what you want. You can get the pdf at:
https://github.com/rougier/scientific-visualization-book#read-the-book

In this case you can use `ax.transData` to transform your data coordinates (from `rect2.get_bbox()`) to Figure coordinates. And subsequently transform those with the inverted `ax.transAxes` to convert from Figure to Axes coordinates. That last step corrects for the position of the axes in the figure (there's usually some buffer/padding).

So given your example, starting with the bounding box of `rect2`, which is in data coordinates:

```py
bbox = rect2.get_bbox()
# Bbox([[10.0, 10.0], [50.0, 30.0]])
```

You can define the transformation with:

```py
data_to_figure = ax.transData.transform
data_to_axes = lambda x: ax.transAxes.inverted().transform(data_to_figure(x))
```

Then transforming the bbox from data coordinates to axes coordinates:

```py
data_to_axes(bbox)
```

Results in:

```py
array([[0.13636364, 0.22727273],
       [0.5       , 0.59090909]])
```

Note that Matplotlib automatically adds some padding to the x- and y limits of the axes, based on the data plotted. So when explicitly setting the axes limits equal to your data, the rectangle coordinates (in axes coordinates) match your intuition:

```py
# add
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 50)

data_to_axes(bbox)
```

Results in:

```py
array([[0.1, 0.2],
       [0.5, 0.6]])
```

This is more or less identical to what's explained on page 21 & 22 in the above mentioned book.

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent answer @RutgerKassies - and especially for the reference to the book!